# Возникновение ошибки Segmentation fault

Tags: c

Цель записывать строки без знаков разделения, и в конечном итоге их вывести.
Концом ввода служит "~"

[image: Результат работы программы]

Собственно сам код программы:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#define LENBUF 1024
#define NUMSTR 64

int issep(char c)
{
    return (c==' ' || c=='\t') ? 0 : 1;
}

void isfull(int j)
{
    if(j>LENBUF)
    {
        printf("Переполнение буфера! Введите меньшее кол-во символов!");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void out(char *res[])
{
    int i=0;
    putchar('\n');
    while(res[i]!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", res[i]);
        i++;
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    char *m, c, buf[LENBUF], *res[NUMSTR];
    int i, j=0, k=0;
    while((c=getchar())!='~')
        if(issep(c))
            if(c!='\n')
            {
                buf[j]=c;
                j++;
                isfull(j);
            }
            else
            {
                buf[j]='\0';
                if((m=(char*)malloc((j+1)*sizeof(char)))==NULL)
                {
                    perror("Ошибка выделения памяти");
                    exit(1);
                }
                for(i=0;i<=j;i++)
                   m[i]=buf[i];
                res[k]=m;
                k++; j=0;
            }
    res[k+1]=NULL;
    out(res);
}
```

Comment: Ну очевидно в конце должно быть `res[k]=NULL;`, а не `res[k+1]=NULL;`. Отлаживать свои программы вас не учили?

Comment: @AnT спасибо большое)